# KDE crashes with X2Go on Kubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, kde, crash, kubuntu, x2go

[X2Go](https://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php) won't connect to my Kubuntu 16.04 PC, while MATE and XFCE work well with X2Go. X2Go has an older version of X server built in and doesn't support some newer features; apparently that's why MATE and XFCE work well with it.

X2Go does connect OK to a KDE VM with almost identical configuration, except of course the video driver will be different. I suspect the video driver may be the issue on my Kubuntu PC (since it works when connecting to a VM).

How should I configure it to be compatible with X2Go ? Should I remove the NVidia driver? If so, how do I remove it?

Here's some output showing the problem:

**Error:**

GUI Error (shows on physically connected display, not x2go)

```
Sorry Ubuntu 16.04 has experienced an internal error 
Executable path:    /usr/bin/ksplashqml 
Architecture: AMD 
Title: ksplashqml crashed with signal 7 in malloc_consolidate()
```

Syslog

```
May 10 10:26:04 Computer1234 /usr/bin/x2goruncommand: launching session with Xsession-x2go mechanism, using STARTUP="startkde"
May 10 10:26:04 Computer1234 /usr/bin/x2goruncommand: dbus wrapper available as /usr/bin/dbus-run-session
May 10 10:26:05 Computer1234 kernel: [xxx] x2goagent[xxx]: segfault at 0 ip xxx sp yyy error 4 in nxagent[xxx]
```

Comment: https://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php/doc:de-compat notes it's good with KDE 3 and KDE4, but glacially slow with the KDE 5 in Kubuntu 16.04 LTS. They ask you to  please join the X2Go-User Mailing List or, if you are certain you've found a bug, subscribe to X2Go-Dev and file a bug report.

Comment: Thanks k7aay for the info, might be a good idea for me to join that mailing list. It is working fine on the VM though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

X2Go is crashing because the system is configured to use an NVidia video driver. This is the reason why connecting to an almost identical VM works - as the VM is of course using a different video driver.

Solution:

- Go to the Linux machine running the X2Go server.
- Click on K Start Menu >> System Settings (in Computer tab) >> Driver Manager
- Select "Using X.Org X server -- Nouveau driver from xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
- Apply, then reboot